# Corded vs Cordless Drill

Tags: tools, drill, powertools

I have the intension of buying a Drill, At shops, I see the corded and cordless Types, Although the cordless drill is more handy and portable, I always have a little doubt about that it's effectiveness and efficiency might not be as the corded type.....Is it true and also is choosing a cheaper manufacturer going because they are cheaper going to affect the quality of the Drill?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been asked here before.

Answer (score 3):

Go to any site where they are building homes.  80-90%+ of drills there will be cordless.   Until the past 5-10 years most consumer cordless drills were almost worthless for heavy duty jobs.  But that simply isn't true anymore.  The big boxes carry good brands and you can get more than enough power from a $200 cordless drill that comes with two batteries and a charger.

The downfall of the corded drill is you need electricity.  I would say 1/3 of the time I am using my drill I have no or poor access to electricity.  If you are drilling on a bench next to a socket then this shouldn't concern you.  Also if I am working around a house it is rather annoying having to plug and unplug drill or keep it from getting caught on something.

I have a corded drill.  It has two uses.  I use it when I am mixing cement/thinset or something similar.  Doing this with cordless isn't a great idea.  The other is when I forget to charge my batteries.

Note: one negative is that I misplace my makita almost daily.  Doesn't happen with corded.  But then kids don't get to play "find dads makita".

Comment: I agree with the previous poster -- the corded drill is probably better for most homeowners who need it infrequently (and who stay within an extension cord's reach of an outlet). I bought a nice $200 cordless drill a couple years ago, and now one battery pack won't charge, and the other has a very short lifetime - when I looked at buying a replacement battery, I found that I could buy a nice corded drill for less than the price of a battery pack, so that's what I did. I thought the $200 drill would last me for many years, but didn't count on the short battery lifetime.

Comment: @johnny valid point but I use mine 20 plus times a week at home... Not plugging it in everytime period.  So I guess usage per week is a good indicator too

Answer (score 1):

For a professional, a cordless drill is a no-brainer. You're frequently away from a power source, moving around all the time, using it frequently enough that keeping it charged isn't a concern, and using it so hard that it will likely burn out and require replacement before the battery dies and the product line becomes obsolete and they don't sell batteries any more. And you can write off the purchase as a business expense.

For all these same reasons, a cordless drill doesn't make sense for a homeowner, in my opinion. You'll be using it in and around the house nearly all the time, with ample access to power. The infrequency of use will mean that unless you keep the battery constantly charging, it'll be out of power when you need to use it. And since you'll probably want to keep it for 10 years or more, it will be a major hassle when they stop making the batteries in 5. A corded drill is also cheaper than a cordless drill. Typical homeowner use will not destroy even the cheapest drill.

Comment: I disagree that homeowners don't need a cordless drill. I use my cordless drill on outside building projects all the time. A 100' extension cord won't even reach the back third of my property either. Of course, a homeowner who will use their drill twice in 5 years may want to go corded.

Comment: I guess it depends on how big your property is! :)

Comment: I keep a 50' and a 30' extension cord. There's no corner of the property I cannot reach with them. My experience with cordless tools, is that after the first year or two, the batteries are *always* dead when you want to use them. Unless the industry has standardized power pack design, you'll find that replacement batteries do not come cheap.